# how to generate stackedBar chart using apache poi 4.0 XDDFChartData, XDDFBarChartData ; in excel sheet using java, i dont want to use jfree

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, stackedbarseries

I need a sample code in Java, currently I am able to draw line and pie charts charts after reading values from sheet, and I also want to generate a StackedBar chart.

I added a snipplet of code for pie chart which I have attempted which is for .ppt format.
I want the same in excel for stackedBar chart in java.

---

```
String[] categories = listCategories.toArray(new String[listCategories.size()]);
            Double[] values = listValues.toArray(new Double[listValues.size()]);

            final int numOfPoints = categories.length;
            final String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
            final String valuesDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
            final XDDFDataSource<?> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange);
            final XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> valuesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values, valuesDataRange);

            XDDFPieChartData.Series firstSeries = (XDDFPieChartData.Series) pie.getSeries().get(0);
            firstSeries.replaceData(categoriesData, valuesData);
            firstSeries.setTitle(chartTitle, chart.setSheetTitle(chartTitle, 0));
            firstSeries.setExplosion(25);
            chart.plot(pie);
```

Comment: What have you tried? There is a [BarChat](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BarChart.java) example. And there is [XDDFBarChartData.setBarGrouping](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFBarChartData.html#setBarGrouping-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.BarGrouping-) and [BarGrouping.STACKED](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/BarGrouping.html#STACKED)

Comment: HI thanks for your revert, can u pls share an example snippet for stacked bar graph, also can u pls let me know how can i add data labels using code in java for the same graphs

Comment: Click on the [BarChart](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BarChart.java) link. Look at the code. You will find `// looking for "Stacked Bar Chart"? uncomment the following line` - `// bar.setBarGrouping(BarGrouping.STACKED);`.

Comment: is this possible to use the stacked bar and line chart in the same graph???

Comment: Yes it is possible but not using only the `XDDF`stuff. Some corrections using the low level beans are necessary. But that was not the question here. SO works as: One concrete question -> multiple possible answers to this question. It does not work as: One vague question plus additional questioons in comments -> some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Stacked is not working correctly with poi 4.12, I uncommented the code in the example and the bars are next to each other and not on top of each other.

Comment: found a solution in this post: https://roytuts.com/how-to-generate-stacked-bar-chart-or-column-chart-in-excel-using-apache-poi/

chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).addNewOverlap().setVal((byte) 100);