# How to generate editable Stacked-bar-chart using apache poi 4.0.1 and java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, stacked-chart, apache-poi-4

**I want to create stacked bar chart using Apache poi 4.0.1 and Java language for Excel**

- The output excel file's extension should be .xlsx
- The generated chart should have Chart title and Data Labels
- The generated chart should also be able to show the total sum of all data at the top of each column (you can see total for each column is shown in yellow boxes)
- You can refer following image for more clarity about what I'm looking for.

---

[image]

---

> - Data for stacked bar chart

---

```
Date    Category High Medium Low
10/01   3        0    3      0
10/02   3        0    2      1
10/03   3        0    2      1
10/04   4        1    2      1
10/05   11       1    7      3
10/08   14       1    10     3
10/09   15       1    11     3
10/10   15       1    11     3
10/11   15       0    11     4
10/12   8        0    6      2
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901830/how-to-generate-stackedbar-chart-using-apache-poi-4-0-xddfchartdata-xddfbarchar. There is an example `BarChart` linked already. Please try this and tell us why this not fullfills your requirements. To your screenshot:This is not useful without having at least the chart's underlying data provided. Please provide this data.

Comment: @AxelRichter I've added data to the body part of question.

Comment: You have added a picture of the data. So possible helpers needs manually retyping the data from that picture. The data is not as much. So why not providing them as text in the question? And what about my other suggestion? Have you tried the `BarChat.java` example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derived from the bar chart and line chart examples in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ we also can get a combined chart as requested here. But until now not all requested is possible only using the high level `XDDF` classes. Some correcting are necessary for which we need using the underlying low level `ooxml-schemas-1.4` beans. So `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` needs to be in class path.

In following code the following changes where made to the official examples:

`leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);` is set. So category axis crosses the value axis between the strokes and not midpoint the strokes. Else the bars are only half wide visible for first and last category.

`chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).addNewOverlap().setVal((byte)100);` sets an overlap of 100%. Else the bars of the single series are not really stacked but remains side by side.

Adding data labels is only possible using the underlying low level `ooxml-schemas-1.4` beans.

The additional line chart must have it's own axes which are crossing each other properly. But those axes must be invisible.

Because while adding to the chart, the line chart does not knows something about the already present bar chart, it's `ID`s starts with 0 again. But this is wrong for an combined chart. So we need correct the id and order. It must not start with 0 again because there are three bar series already.

Following code needs a `StackedBarAndLineChart.xlsx` having the data provided in the question in first sheet in range `A1:E11`.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

public class StackedBarAndLineChart {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("StackedBarAndLineChart.xlsx"); 
       XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(in)) {
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   // determine the type of the category axis from it's first category value (value in A2 in this case)
   XDDFDataSource date = null;
   CellType type = CellType.ERROR;
   Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
   if (row != null) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
    if (cell != null) {
     type = cell.getCellType();
     if (type == CellType.STRING) {   
      date = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 0, 0));
     } else  if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {  
      date = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 0, 0));
     } else  if (type == CellType.FORMULA) {  
      type = cell.getCachedFormulaResultType();
      if (type == CellType.STRING) {   
       date = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 0, 0));
      } else  if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {  
       date = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 0, 0));
      }
     }
    }
   }
   if (date != null) { // if no type of category axis found, don't create a chart at all    
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> high = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 2, 2));
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> medium = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 3, 3));
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> low = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 4, 4));
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 1, 1));

    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 16, 20);

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);

    // bar chart

    XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setTitle("Number of defects");
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

    // category axis crosses the value axis between the strokes and not midpoint the strokes
    leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

    XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
    XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(date, high);
    series1.setTitle("high", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 2, true, true));
    XDDFChartData.Series series2 = data.addSeries(date, medium);
    series2.setTitle("medium", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 3, true, true));
    XDDFChartData.Series series3 = data.addSeries(date, low);
    series3.setTitle("low", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 4, true, true));
    chart.plot(data);

    XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
    bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);

    // looking for "Stacked Bar Chart"? uncomment the following line
    bar.setBarGrouping(BarGrouping.STACKED);

    // correcting the overlap so bars really are stacked and not side by side
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).addNewOverlap().setVal((byte)100);

    solidFillSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.CORNFLOWER_BLUE);
    solidFillSeries(data, 1, PresetColor.LIGHT_SALMON);
    solidFillSeries(data, 2, PresetColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

    // add data labels
    for (int s = 0 ; s < 3; s++) {
     chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(s).addNewDLbls();
     chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(s).getDLbls()
      .addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.CTR);
     chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(s).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
     chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(s).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
     chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(s).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
     chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(s).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
    }

    // line chart

    // axis must be there but must not be visible
    bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setVisible(false);
    leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setVisible(false);

    // set correct cross axis
    bottomAxis.crossAxis(leftAxis);
    leftAxis.crossAxis(bottomAxis);

    data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
    XDDFLineChartData.Series series4 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series)data.addSeries(date, category);
    series4.setTitle("total", null);
    series4.setSmooth(false);
    series4.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.STAR);
    chart.plot(data);

    // correct the id and order, must not start 0 again because there are three bar series already
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(3);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(3);

    solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.YELLOW);

    // add data labels
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
     .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)255,(byte)255,0});
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
     .addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.CTR);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
   }

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("StackedBarAndLineChartResult.xlsx")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }

 private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setFillProperties(fill);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }

 private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
  line.setFillProperties(fill);
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setLineProperties(line);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Edit 2019-03-01:

I have improved my code a little bit. It now determines the type of the category axis from it's first category value (value in A2 in this case). And for the data labels explicitly the position is set and it is explicitly set that only the values should shown but not legend key, category name or series name.

Comment: I've created excel file with "StackedBarAndLineChart.xlsx" name. I also added ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar in class path. But I'm getting following exception.
-----------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData$Series.fillStringCache(XDDFChartData.java:264)
 at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData$Series.plot(XDDFChartData.java:157)
 at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChart.plot(XDDFChart.java:344)
 at xls.StackedBarAndLineChart.main(StackedBarAndLineChart.java:50)

Comment: @shubham pawar: My column `A` is a text column. The values in `A2`=`10/01` and `A3`=`10/02` and also `A4:A11` is text in my `Excel`. It seams to be date values in your `Excel`. But `10/01` is not any meaningful date in my locale. But then `XDDFDataSource<String> date = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange...` is wrong. Please do changing `A2:A11` to be text too. Will try this afternoon (Germany) how it can work when `A2:A11` are date values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Axel.
I've changed column "A" to text and now excel file is creating but there is a problem with Data Labels. The data labels showing three values (Example - Total,10/06,11) on chart instead of just one value(Example - 11). How can I sort this issue?

Comment: @shubham pawar: What `Excel` version? Maybe we must set `.getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);` explicitly and also `.getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);`.

Comment: @AlexRichter          I'm using Excel 2013. Now, It's creating a chart with values but values are on right side of bar instead of exactly middle of the bar.

Comment: @shubham pawar: I improved have my code a little bit. It now determines the type of the category axis from it's first category value (value in A2 in this case). And for the data labels explicitly the position is set and it is explicitly set that only the values should shown but not legend key, category name or series name.

Comment: Thank you so much Axel. It is working properly. I'll ask more questions about apache poi soon 