# Apache POI - PowerPoint Bar and Line Chart

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm trying to make a bar and line chart using Apache POI in Powerpoint like this:

[image: Exameple bar and line chart]

I found a [solution for
excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065690/apache-poi-cant-get-line-chart-values-to-appear-in-the-secondary-axis) to the problem, but it creates the chart in Excel instead of PowerPoint, my question now is, is there a way to convert the code in the other solution to one that works for PowerPoint, so I can add it to a slide. And have the input as lists instead of rows/columns in the excel file?

Comment: First step: [how to create a chart in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373942/java-create-a-chart-in-a-powerpoint-using-apache-poi), then modify the output pptx in PowerPoint, then unzip the pptx file and look at the added xml elements (i.e. compare the files), last step: recreate the missing xml elements via the XmlBeans interface. this will be a trial and error process, so make only small adjustments in PowerPoint.

Comment: I probably should add that we have a XDDF interface / generalization. I currently can't browse the code, but you might find some examples in the [examples artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-examples/5.0.0/jar) or in the [tests](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/test/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696090/show-sum-value-above-stacked-bar-with-apache-poi/62716111#62716111. This creates a combination of stacked bar chart and line chart in `PowerPoint`. The line chart is not visible and not shown in a separate axis. But this easily can be changed .

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! Will try to figure it out, thanks again!